# What meaning ぬち いっ?

Tags: manga, japanese-to-english, onomatopoeia

“ぬちいっ” it's an onomatopoeia that appeared in a manga but I don't understand what it means.
in the manga it appears with a space (like this: ぬち いっ)

Comment: It is not a standard one. Can you give the picture or more descriptions of drawing?

Comment: Ya, definitely more context needed -- and since this is a manga, visual context would be ideal.